# Snowflake Security - Grants to modify views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to figure out what privileges to give a role so that role can alter views in a certain database/schema. I've tried a bunch of times but can't get anything to allow it to work.

The view is MyDatabase.Public.vw_TestView. I need my user to be able to update the view with changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The role will need ownership privileges on the view in order to alter it:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#view-privileges

And as it says in the documentation note: "Operating on a view also requires the USAGE privilege on the parent database and schema."

Comment: Thank you so much. I started to go down that path and thought surely that can't be it. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.